# url rewriting - dipslys an extra parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am rewriting my website URLs in clean URLs (using `.htaccess`) . I have written this rule in my `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)/([^/]+) front/detailsnew.php?catid=$1&title=$2 [NC]
```

But the URL displays as this:

```
My domain /details/Apartments/409-Palm-Beach-Condos#ad-image-0
```

I don't want the `#ad-image-0` to be shown. My a href link is

```
My domain/details/European/Test-Bisuwer
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: From what I can see, the `.htaccess` file looks fine... Without seeing the pages themselves, all I can do is suggest you check the HTML or try entering the URL without the hashtag and see how the page reacts. If it adds the hashtag, then you know JavaScript is playing a role.

Answer (score 2):

in your `jquery.ad-gallery.js` file you need to remove this following lines

Line Number above 500

comment 2 lines : `window.location.hash = "#ad-image-"+ thumb_link.attr("id");`

```
 if(this.settings.update_window_hash) {
            var thumb_link = this.images[this.current_index].thumb_link;
            if (thumb_link.attr("id")) {
              //window.location.hash = "#ad-image-"+ thumb_link.attr("id");
            } else {
              //window.location.hash = "#ad-image-"+ this.current_index;
            };
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#` part of the URL is a *fragment*. It's never sent to the server and is used solely by the client (browser) for handling the content or in some cases, a way for AJAX or other javascript to communicate with each other. There's nothing you can do in your htaccess file to remove it. The browser is generating it on its own. But looking at the fragment, and googling for it, it may have something to do with [AD Gallery](http://adgallery.codeplex.com/), there's people who mention getting `ad-image-` fragments when using AD Gallery.